# Why does partial application require to specify a parameter type?

Tags: scala, type-inference, partial-application

Why does partial function application in Scala require a type to be supplied, like in:

```
def func(a: Int, b: Int) = ???

def func1 = func(_ : Int, 1) // compiles fine

def func1x = func(_, 1) // does not compile
// error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2) => func(x$2, 1))
```

Why is type not inferred in this case? Would inferring type lead to a complicated or ambiguous grammar, or is the type perhaps not as clear as it seems to me?

Comment: FYI, you can easily avoid situations like that by just giving type annotations to your top level definitions. That's good for documentation purposes anyway.

Comment: @Cubic I am afraid I do not understand. Can you show an example how would that look like in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the compile error you can see that `func(_, 1)` expands to `x => func(x, 1)`. If you first wrote `def f = x => func(x, 1)`, there is no guarantee that `x` is an `Int`. [SLS 6.23.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions) unfortunately says nothing about filling in the type ascription when one is not explicitly given.

`List(1, 2, 3).map(_ + 1)` works because `map` expects an argument of `Int => Int`. `def func1x = func(_, 1)` does not work because the type of `func1x` is inferred from the right-hand-side, but there isn't technically known either. It would only make sense to infer `x: Int => f(x, 1)`, but I'd guess that would add another unnecessary complexity for the compiler to have to handle the corner case for placeholder syntax on method arguments.